# What does "of late he had fallen on evil days" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

A sentence from George Orwell's *Animal Farm*:

> In past years Mr. Jones, although a hard master, had been a capable farmer, but of late he had fallen on evil days.

You can find the entire chapter at [this link](http://www.marxists.org/subject/art/literature/children/texts/orwell/animal-farm/ch02.htm).

What does *of* in "of late" mean, and how is it used here?
What does "had fallen on evil days" mean? Is it an idiom?
What does the whole sentence mean?

I noticed "had been a capable farmer" and "had fallen" are using the same tense, but I guess by using "but of late", there should be some differences between the two timings.

Comment: The meaning of _of late_ is the same as _lately_.

Comment: See Oald, late and of late:  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/late_2#late_2__193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on the answer given by Ankit:

*of late* = recently

*had fallen on evil days* = had been having problems, or difficulties.  I would not consider it an idiom myself, but perhaps it was a more common usage in the author's era.

To re-word the sentence in an attempt to make its meaning clearer:

> Mr. Jones had always been a hard master, but he had also always been a capable farmer until recently, when some problems developed that he was unable to resolve satisfactorily.

Comment: This is a good answer. The only thing I would add is the meaning of "evil" in context. Here it does not mean "morally reprehensible". It means "causing harm, marked by misfortune".

Answer (score 4):

Here "of late" means recently and  "had fallen on evil days" means "hard times".

Comment: I was quite surprised to find that *evil days* was actually more common (in print, at least) that *hard times* [right up until the early 70s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fallen+on+hard+times%2Cfallen+on+evil+days&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfallen%20on%20hard%20times%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfallen%20on%20evil%20days%3B%2Cc0). I though it was just that Orwell had already used ***hard master***, so he needed a different expression. But apparently he was using the standard one for his time.